# How can I install a Gnome Applet without privileges

Tags: gnome-panel, unprivileged

I would like to install [stackapplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-stackoverflow-meets-the-gnome-desktop-v1-2-released), but I don't have superuser privileges to install the deb file and the admins will not install it for me.

I'm confident that I must be able to install this applet without privileges, but I can't seem to find a really good guide.

What are the steps I need to take to install this applet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I have not been able to test the following , but I hope it gives us some direction

http://old.nabble.com/installing-a-panel-applet-without-being-root-td9261908.html

Answer (score 1):

AFAICS you cannot install stackapplet without superuser privilege because every gnome applet has [Bonobo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonobo_%28component_model%29) control file (GNOME_AppletName.server) which is in /usr/lib/bonobo/server You Must have bonobo control file to use applet and you cannot edit /usr/lib/bonobo folder unless you have sudo privilege. There is also bonobo-activation-config file in /etc/ which i believe contains path for the bonovo server files. If you can add your custom path then it may help but again you need sudo to edit that file.

But i cannot say its impossible :) there might be some way which i don't know.